Highlight cell a color if there is a duplicate entry
I have a SharePoint list that tracks client names. Each client has a specific ID.
If there is a duplicate ID entry, I would like the cells to turn a certain color, is this possible?

As far as I know, this is not possible using SharePoint Online JSON formatting by default.
In column/view JSON formatting, you cannot access/use the column values from another list item/row.
You can only access the column values from the SAME list item/row like [$AnotherColumnFromSameRow].
Where AnotherColumnFromSameRow is internal name another column from same list item/row.
You can get the internal name of your list columns by following this article: How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?.
Similar thread: How can JSON column formatting be used to highlight duplicate entries in a column a list?

You can create a new column (Example: "Is Duplicate?" - Yes or No) in your list and use any custom solution (like scheduled Power automate flow) to update value of that column for the items where duplicate client ID is used.
Then you can highlight columns or rows using this new column values and JSON formatting.
